# HttpClient/BufferedReader returns garbled mess

Tags: java, java-io

I have a method to get the source text of a file from a url and return it as a string. but it returns garbled rubbish instead of anything useful.

I use the same code in one place in my project and it works perfectly fine, but using it elsewhere returns a mess

The code:

```
private static String getWebSource(String Url) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Url); // Set the action you want to do
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
        sb.append(line + "\n");

    String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

    return resString;
}
```

What it returns:

```
������������mRËnÛ0<Û@þaÃCÑ¡hÅ=4¤CíM¦A£Àí×TIúÕ¯/õpìCt ÃÝá.ËÅyþûé*_+xzùüp?B[Nç-òüú8@n¹vÒK£¹bìî��©¼ofív»h7-Yþí[®¸-BêÏ*#áÉÆI'¸¯vé4ñÍÍM_MÚ¤âºL j¯Q6%Â¬6R  ÷®@A½ 4»_%ä"Ãð%5z­"Å¿¹MÉÜhÚÓüÐ ¢ß¥ÄãÞ³ÖÁ-·}ú¡;öNóS"°0{cÏXÐZcÍ³ôC½éo®9W
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with "iso-8859-1".

Comment: I've removed that and run it again and it returns exactly the same

Comment: @DanielKaplan what URL are you calling this function on?

Comment: I'm calling it on http://hertsandessexobserver.co.uk/News.rss which works perfectly and then http://hertsandessexobserver.co.uk/people-van-tried-pick-schoolchildren-Bishop-s/story-25974175-detail/story.html which returns the garbled string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the response is compressed (gzip).
Try to uncompress it:

```
...

InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
if ((contentEncoding != null) && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) { 
    InputStream gzipIs = new GZIPInputStream(is);
    ...
```

Comment: This appears to work beautifully! I'll test it out on a couple of links and see what happens!

Comment: Accepted as answer. I've tested your solution out with various test links and it has worked every time.